# What's wrong in this Code? Netbeans not compiling the code

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors

What's wrong with this piece of code? I am trying to solve a question where we have 2 strings and we have to print how many times we can extract the second string from the first one. When I am running this code, my Netbeans did not responding, it is taking about time in seconds like 25 seconds, 30 seconds like this.

```
public class nine {
  static int res=0;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int c=0;

    String as="nniinneetteeeenn";       // first string

    String ss = "nineteen";             // second string
    char a[]= ss.toCharArray();
    char b[]= as.toCharArray();
    boolean result = true; 

    while(result == true){
      for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++){
          if(a[i]==b[j]){
            b[j]=32;
            res=1;
            break;
          }
        } //j loop ends

        if(res==0)
          break;
      } // i loops ends

      if(res==0)
          result=false;

      else{
          result=true;
             c++;
         }
      } // while loops ends       

      System.out.println(c);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work only if you do not have any matches. Once the res is changed to other than 0. It has no possibility to change back to 0. That's why if your code finds any match then it will go to an infinite loop.

Because once the `res = 1` is executed you never re-assigned it to 0 again. that's why when it executed `res = 1` it goes to an infinite loop

**Edited** You can do this, in your else part just reset res to 0

```
    else{
        result=true;
        c++;
        res=0;
       }
```

Comment: You can do this else{
            result=true;
            c++;
            res=0;
           }

Answer (score 1):

```
if(res==0)
    result=false;
```

Will never execute and therefore your while loop will never terminate.

The reason it will never execute is because `res` will never be re-assigned to zero once your for loop begins.

Comment: why it'll never terminate?

Comment: because your while loop will continue to run as long as result==true. Since the block of code that assigns result to false never hits, the while loop will never stop.